# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, database

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :appointments
has_many :doctors, :through => :appointments
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :appointments
has_many :users, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :doctor
belongs_to :user
end
```

Code to call controller action:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/create",
      data: {
        appointment_date: date,
        doctor_id: "1",
        user_id: "1"
      }
```

// Etc.
        });

Action:

```
def create
@appointment = Appointment.new(:appointment_date, :doctor_id, :user_id)
if @appointment.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
    redirect_to @user
else
    alert("failure!")
end
```

And I got this error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)):
```

How to handle this error? Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply passing the symbols to the Appointment constructor doesn't work.

You need to pass the variables like this:

```
Appointment.new(:appointment_date => params[:appointment_date], ...)
```

Since the params hash already contains all these values, you can pass these in directly like zwippie already showed.

Just a headsup for the future: in case your params hash contains values you don't want to pass to the constructor, use `Appointment.new(params.except(:unwanted_key))`

Comment: Thank you. I've done it like that but I'm receiving the following error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ah I think the ajax doesn't wrap the data in its own param group. Rather, `params[:appointment_date]` (and others) are available, without the [:data]. The direct creation call could then be `Appointment.new(params)` but will throw errors if it contains values not meant for appointment. Use `except()` or other means to filter only the keys you need.

Comment: Oh and another thing: if you regularly need this feature, why not use the Rails builtin ajax forms. Use `form_for @appointment, (options), :remote => true do (...)` to get it to post as ajax. `@appointment` would need to be a new and empty Appointment object. It can also be an existing one which will then convert the form to an edit form. The values are then available as params[:appointment] in your controller and only contain the fields you created.

Answer (score 3):

What if you try:

```
@appointment = Appointment.new(params[:data])
```

Comment: It seems ok now but I'm receiving the following error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass